# Read jpeg out of a stream provided by libcurl

Tags: c++, http, jpeg, libcurl

I have an IP Camera from which ( oh surprise ) I want to get some pictures. For the start I just want to read a single jpeg. Since all communication is done via http I'm using libcurl. So my code looks pretty simple like this:

```
// Initialize some stuff
CURL * curl;
curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.0.147/cgi-bin/mjpeg?mode=single");    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_test);
```

Now I'm quite aware that I need two more things. I need to declare and define the callback function ( write_test ) and I need to call  curl_easy_setopt() with the paramter CURLOPT_WRITEDATA and hand him a stream.

Now this is the case where I am not sure how to do this. If I just hand him a normal filestream and write all the stuff into a file (like it was just some text) it won't work since the normal filestream doesn't understand the jpeg.

How would I do this? Do I need an additional library like "libjpeg" ? And how would I work with the stream?

//edit:

Okay as mentioned I *can* just dump the stream of one single jpeg into a filestream. Now this actually works:

```
FILE* pFile = fopen("/home/username/test.jpeg","w");
curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.0.147/cgi-bin/mjpeg?mode=single");
//curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_test);
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, pFile);
curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

If I don't declare a callback function it works fine - but if I dont comment out the CURLOP_WRITEFUNCTION and declare the callback by myself I get no good results.

->

```
size_t write_test(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmeb, void *stream)
{
    return fwrite(ptr,size,nmeb,static_cast<FILE*>(stream));
}
```

This doesn't work....?

Best Regards

Tobias

Comment: "it won't work since the normal filestream doesn't understand the jpeg." What does it need to understand? If you write the file out in binary mode with a .jpg extension won't that work? Or are you getting data without JFIF headers, or something else? Or hoping to process the file some way first? Or is it giving you a continuous stream you need to cut into individual images, or something else?

Comment: Oh man, sometimes I feel like I shouldn't work this early in the morning - yea ofc I can ( when I just get one picture ) dump all the stream into a file. But I didn't notice something else( just gonna specify it in my question above )

Comment: Your write_test callback function looks OK to me insofar as it doesn't do anything besides call through to `fwrite` with the exact same parameters as it received. Could it be because `write_test` is a C++ function and you need to somehow declare it as a C function (i.e. inside an `extern "C" { }` block)? I don't know C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found out what the problem was:

For debugging purposes I had my "write_test" function implemented like this:

```
size_t write_test(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmeb, void *stream)
{
    memcpy(buffer,ptr,size*nmeb);
    size_t no;

    no = fwrite(ptr,size,nmeb,static_cast<FILE*>(stream));
    printf("no: %d\tsize: %d\tnmeb: %d\n",no,size,nmeb);
    return no;
}
```

Now unfortunately I didnt show you the part with the memcpy ( ye my fault... ). Now if I comment it out the program works. Now I didnt search the problem there since memcpy should not affect my ptr with the data. I guess it didn't **but** I only allocated the buffer with 50 bytes. Since I get like 2kByte everytime the write_test function is called I guess it kinda corrupted the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want it dumped to a file on disk, or do you want to receive it to a memory buffer (or a database, or anything else)? Either way cURL can help you. If you want it in a file then you can use `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` as you've said without setting any `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`. If you want it in a memory buffer then you will have to supply both `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` and `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`, the latter being a pointer to a function you have written that accepts the data coming from the remote server and stores it up somewhere.

What do you want to **do** with the JPEG once you get it? That seems to be outside the scope of your question if I understand it correctly, and it has nothing to do with cURL. "libjpeg" can indeed help you there.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution posted on libcurl's website. This function works perfectly for me with the same target as you!

```
struct MemoryStruct {
    char *memory;
    size_t size;
};  


size_t MailServer::WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *)userp;

    mem->memory = (char *)realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
    if(mem->memory == NULL) {
        /* out of memory! */ 
        printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
        return 0;
    }

    memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
    mem->size += realsize;
    mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;

    return realsize;
}
```

I hope it helps! :D